# Prestashop Code Blocks

Tags: php, content-management-system, smarty, prestashop

I've been thrown in at the Prestashop deep end, have a couple of questions and wondered if anyone could help.

1. I need to add fields to a form. This form was marked-up by me, then somehow integrated into the shop. I've found the CMS page with the form on it, and the following tag is inserted to display the form: **{brochure_request_form}**. I cannot however figure out where the code for this tag is edited!
2. Currently, the customer is emailed upon making an order, but the shop admin doesn't receive an email. I have read that installing the Mail Alerts module will allow this functionality, but it seems bizarre to me that the shop doesn't do this by default - is this the case or is there a setting I need to change?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like a custom function plugin, so you should search for a file named `function.brochure_request_form.php`. The default location is supposed to be the plugins subfolder of wherever Smarty is included from, together with a score of similarly named files. If it's not there - you'll have to look thru the PHP code searching for a line resembling `$smarty->plugin_dir[] = 'some_folder';`, as Smarty can look for these plugins in any folder added to the plugin_dir array.

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to select the answer!